# Is there a way to find out the highest role a user has?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to create a command that can find the highest role that a user has in a server.

I already know there is a `discord.user.top_role` in Python. Is there a Javascript equivalent for that?

I am trying to use this code for a `userinfo` command:

```
if(arg.length === 0) {
    let userInfoEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("User Information")
    .setColor(sender.displayHexColor)
    .setThumbnail(sender.avatarURL)
    .addField("User Name", sender.username)
    .addField("User ID", sender.id)
    .addField("Status", sender.presence.status)
    .addField("User Joined", message.guild.joinedAt)
    .addField("User's Highest Role", sender.highestRole.name)

    message.channel.send(userInfoEmbed);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is.

---

## Discord JS V12

```js
GuildMember.roles.highest
```

## Discord JS V11

```js
GuildMember.highestRole
```

Comment: I have already tried highestRole before and it returns "Undefined." Is there a package I am missing? (I am using v11.3.2 of the discord.js library)

Comment: Does the user have a role?

Comment: Yes the user does have a role

Comment: Edit your question to include the relevant code that you're trying to use

Comment: From where do you get `sender`? @Noobly387 You should have a `let/var sender = something` what is that something? Include also that part please.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by

```
member.roles.highest
```

So it would be

```
sender.roles.highest.name
```